# What is the purpose of structure iov_iter in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

What is the purpose of struct  iov_iter ? This structure is being used in Linux kernel instead of struct  iovec. There is no any good documentation for iter interface. I had found one document on LWN but I am not able to understand that. Could anyone please help me to understand the iter  interface which is being used in Linux kernel ?

Answer (score 3):

One purpose of `iovec`, which the [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/625077/) states up front, is to process data in multiple chunks.

If you have a number of discrete buffers, chained with pointers, and want to read/write them in one go, you could do so with several read/write ops. However, in some cases semantics are associated with read/write boundaries, so ops can't be split without changing the semantics of the operation (a trivial & hypothetical example: an atomic operation that involves more than 1 write). An alternative is to copy all the data in and out of a contiguous buffer, however this is wasteful and you may want to avoid that.

Using the POSIX `readv`/`writev` or, in this case the `iov_iter` API, reduces the number of system calls, and hence the overhead involved. While in the context of kernel code alone this doesn't translate to expensive ops like context switches, it is still a concern. Drivers may also handle large chunks of data more efficiently than they would lots of smaller chunks when they have no way to know if there's more to come in the near future - this is particularly true with network drivers, but nowadays the `iovec`/`iov_iter`/* API is ubiquitous as [`_copy_to_iter`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.7/source/lib/iov_iter.c#L310)/[`_copy_from_iter`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.7/source/lib/iov_iter.c#L383) are used to implement core functions for packet handling code e.g. [`skb_copy_datagram_from_iter`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.7/source/net/core/datagram.c#L541).

Another instance of the same situation is I/O to raw disk
devices, which only allow I/O to start and end of block
boundaries. A user might occasionally want to perform random access or overwrite a small piece of the buffer at, say, the start of a block and/or zero the rest.
Scenarios like that is exactly what `iovec` aimed to address; you can construct an `iovec` which enables you to do a whole block operation spread over several discrete buffers, which might even include a "scratch" buffer for dumping the parts of a block you read and don't care about processing, and a pre-zeroed buffer for chaining at the end of `writev` to zero out the rest of a block. Again, I should point out you *can* use a contiguous buffer with associated copying and/or zeroing, but the `iov_iter` API provides an alternative abstraction which involves less overhead, and is arguably easier to reason about when reading the code.

The term for operations like these in vector processing, or parallel computing, is "*scatter/gather processing*".